# Can't fetch needed data from database using FoxPro

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

My teacher asked me to select some information from a database using FoxPro.

I need to get code_car, car_info, and the sum of rout_dist that have a date_exec month of January, where the sum of rout_dist in January is not bigger than the sum of rout_dist in February, and group it by code_car.

I need something like this:

```
SELECT cm.code_car, info_car, SUM(rout_dist)
    FROM car_move cm
    INNER JOIN car_list cl
        ON cm.code_car = cl.code_car
    WHERE 
        (SELECT SUM(rout_dist)
            FROM car_move cm
            INNER JOIN car_list cl
                ON cm.code_car = cl.code_car
            WHERE MONTH(date_exec) = 1) >
        (SELECT SUM(rout_dist)
            FROM car_move cm
            INNER JOIN car_list cl
                ON cm.code_car = cl.code_car
            WHERE MONTH(date_exec) = 1)
    GROUP BY cm.code_car
```

The database structure:

[image: this is a database structure]

Comment: You need to add some code here. You can't expect us to figure out the problem without more context.

Comment: add one of my tries

Comment: In the example you're showing, both of your subqueries grab January information. Also, you're totally for all Januaries, not just January of a particular year. You need to include the year in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you still don't have a complete answer, you had a good idea on the WHERE subqueries, but lets take one piece at a time.  You want queries for January vs February, but of the current year, not all years.  We can get this per car in one query with a slight trick for you, but common throughout many others as they learn more querying.

```
select
      cm.code_car,
      sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 1, cm.rout_dist, 00000 )) as JanTotal,
      sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 2, cm.rout_dist, 00000 )) as FebTotal
   from
      car_move cm
   where
          cm.Date_Exec >= date(2020,1,1)
      AND cm.Date_Exec < date(2020,3,1)
   group by
      cm.code_car
```

(I know in VFP directly you need semi-colon after each line or it errors on you)
So as I know you are aware of the IIF(), this is confirming the month and only summing the amount if it is the month in question and differentiating between January and February.  The Where clause is expclicitly getting anything on/after Jan 1, 2020 and LESS than March 1, 2020.  So you know you will only get Jan / Feb records.

Now, one caveat on VFP SQL-Select.  It actually runs the query once to get a record for the final structure for the results and then runs again to actually populate the result query.  If the size of the rout_dist is larger than 5 digits, just expand it to make sure values don't get truncated.

Look at the results of the above first...

This also pre-groups by the code_car all in one.  So now, once you confirm the functionality results of just the summation is ok, now we can take it to the next step and exclude some records and get car details of those remaining.  The above query becomes the "FROM" source of records and is given an alias of "PreQuery" and is only for context only since the inner query is done and results returned before the outer query, hence I aliased it "PreQuery".

```
select
      PreQuery.Code_Car,
      cl.info_car,
      PreQuery.JanTotal
   from
      ( select
              cm.code_car,
              sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 1, cm.rout_dist, 00000 )) as JanTotal,
              sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 2, cm.rout_dist, 00000 )) as FebTotal
           from
              car_move cm
           where
                  cm.Date_Exec >= date(2020,1,1)
              AND cm.Date_Exec < date(2020,3,1)
           group by
              cm.code_car ) PreQuery
         JOIN Car_List cl
            on PreQuery.Code_Car = cl.Code_Car
   where
      PreQuery.JanTotal < PreQuery.FebTotal
```

There are many other tricks, especially on very complex queries where you can break them down into smaller sections by query INTO CURSOR which creates a temporary table which can then be one of the queries following in another SQL just as if it too is an actual table.

Comment: I try to midify your code and add output that dist in february is grether, can i delete this rows? (prefer subqueries)
`SELECT cm.code_car, cl.info_car,;
  IIF(sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 1, cm.rout_dist, 0.0 )) > sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 2, cm.rout_dist, 0.0 )), str(sum( iif( month( cm.Date_Exec ) = 2, cm.rout_dist, 0.0 ))), 'sum in january is greater');
 FROM car_move cm INNER JOIN car_list cl ON cm.code_car = cl.code_car;
 GROUP BY cm.code_car;
`
also when i try to use subqury in FROM foxpro raise error.